# Problems returning name in table 2 from id in table 1

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting an error in this query

I have two tables, `dbo.litters` and `dbo.dogs`.

The information of all dogs is in the `dbo.dogs` table and are referenced only by `ID` in the `dbo.litters` table.

Version 2

```
Select 
    Puppy.Reg, Puppy.Name, puppy.LitterId, 
    p1.Reg, p1.Name, p2.Reg, p2.Name
From 
    dbo.Dogs Puppy 
Join 
    dbo.litters as p on Puppy.LitterId = p.Id
Join 
    dbo.Dogs as p1 on Puppy.Id = p.FatherId
Join 
    dbo.Dogs as p2 on Puppy.Id = p.MotherId
Where 
    puppy.Reg = 'xxxxx/xxxx'
```

[Results of the query version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UsFy.png)

I want to show the mother and father of the puppy and this information is only in the `dbo.litters` table.

I'm new to this and I can't see where I go wrong.

```
Select 
    d.id, d.Reg, d.Name, d.LitterId, l.FatherId, l.MotherId
From 
    dbo.Dogs D 
inner join 
    dbo.Litters L on d.LitterId = l.Id
where 
    d.Reg = 'XXXXXX/XXXX'`
```

This query returns the information I need but not the name of the mother and father.

The results looks like this

```
ID      Reg nr       Name    LitterID     Father ID   MotherID
---------------------------------------------------------------
20590   xxxxx/xxxx   Fido    8525         11942       12007
```

I have made a small version in fiddle so everyone see the structure :)

[Database in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1e7d00681732aadabf9fd35473a9233)

[Database in fiddle with solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b07feaee3a978584fdfde0688d8a1c99)

Comment: Huh?  What is `dbo.Litters`?

Comment: it is the table for the Litters information

Comment: On your last query, where does this column (`puppy.Reg`) come from???  I don't see it in the query.

Comment: i have updated with pictures and a copy in fiddle. It still dont work but thanks for all the help :)

Comment: The whole point of a fiddle is that people can actually play with your code, a picture of a fiddle is useless.

Comment: @HoneyBadger here is the link to Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1e7d00681732aadabf9fd35473a9233

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions such that *existing answers* are rendered invalid. Your question now is vastly different to the one you first asked, and no longer matches the title. This is *not* how you should be using SO.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever im sorry this was my first post and i dident think about the heading. Will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used alias for table name but in time of join that does not used. That's why it thrown error, so use  alias name in join:

```
Select 
    d.id, d.Regnr, d.Name, d.LitterId, l.FatherId, l.MotherId,D1.Name as fathername,
    D2.Name as motherName
From dbo.Litters L

left  join  dbo.Dogs D
     on d.LitterId = l.Id
    left join dbo.Dogs D1 on L.FatherId=D1.ID
    left join dbo.Dogs D2 on L.MotherId=D2.ID
where 
    d.Regnr = 'NO34567/2012'

id      Regnr      Name     LitterId    FatherId    MotherId    fathername  motherName
3   NO34567/2012    Fido     9000          2         1               king       Queen
```

Comment: @jim share your tables column name and your expected output in question your question is not much clear

Comment: i tryed your last edit but got errors then i changed it a little and got the query to run but without any errors but no results either

Comment: @Jim use left join instead inner join

Comment: @Jim https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20cd185798c15f4eeea00d8a49f2d5f9 create your table here in fiddle

Comment: here are the link to Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1e7d00681732aadabf9fd35473a9233

Comment: @Jim https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8a150766c8bfab356b3cf1389684a11d i edited answer check now

Answer (score 0):

You want information about a litter, so that's where you start. Next, you want to limit to the litter of one pup, so you join the dog, and filter on its reg. Finally you want to add information about its parents, so you join those specific dogs. You end up with something like:

```
Select puppy.Reg
,      puppy.Name
,      puppy.LitterId
,      dad.Reg
,      dad.Name
,      mom.Reg
,      mom.Name 
From   dbo.litters as l
Join   dbo.Dogs puppy
    on Puppy.LitterId = l.Id 
Join   dbo.Dogs as dad
    on dad.id = l.FatherId 
Join   dbo.Dogs as mom
   on  mom.Id = l.MotherId 
Where  puppy.Reg = 'xxxxx/xxxx'
```

I had to guess those join conditions, because you didn't provide the information.

Comment: The problem i think is that mom and dads id is not known before the query are run, because the mother/father ID is first found when you have found the litter id of the dog you are searching for. So first i have to find the dog (XXXXXX/XXXX) then i get the litters id as a respons and then i look up in dbo.litters and find mother/father ID and take this results back to dbo.dogs to find the name to that ID

Comment: Mom and dad's id doesn't have to be known if it's stored in the same litter row as the pub. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] if this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Jim thanks for the fiddle, what's the issue with my solution now?